# Reverse Engineer MySQL Wworkbench with calculated (generated) fields

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Attempts to reverse engineer as schema with MySQL Workbench fail with the following error:

```
16:06:46 [ERR][            grt]: (127, 53) "GENERATED" is not valid at this position, expecting ')' 
16:06:46 [ERR][            grt]: (149, 53) "GENERATED" is not valid at this position, expecting ')'
```

The reason for this are the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Fullname` varchar(250) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat_ws(' ',`Firstname`,`Name`)) VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teacher` (
  `Abbr` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FullName` varchar(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat_ws(' ',`Firstname`,`Name`)) VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Abbr`)
);
```

How do I reverse engineer a schema which relations can contain generated attributes?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work. You have to remove the generated columns to do reverse engineer in MySQL Workbench.

This was reported as a bug in 2018: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92267

I'm afraid MySQL Workbench gets poor resources for improvement, and it has fallen behind several features of MySQL Server. I also discovered the reverse engineer feature doesn't work if you use an expression as the `DEFAULT` of a column.

To make my diagram, I had to make a special test instance of my database, alter the tables that had expression defaults, and then do the reverse engineer step. I suggest you will have to do the same — make a special instance and remove your generated columns.

Comment: Thanks, Was afraid of that. It is really a pity that such a feature rich program falls so short on support. And yes I had my share of problems with WB using it in teaching setting. Good to know it isn't me